# Suitescript 2.0 - log.debug repeating value lines

Tags: suitescript

I'm working on a client script, but when I do a simple getValue() on the customer field and log.debug, I get repeating output lines and I'm not sure why. Is this normal?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR50Q.png)

This my fieldChanged code:

```
function fieldChanged(context) {
    var newRec = context.currentRecord;
    if(newRec.fieldId = 'entity') {

        var custId = newRec.getValue ({
            fieldId: 'entity'
        });

        log.debug({
            title: 'id: ' + custId
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line below:

```
if(newRec.fieldId = 'entity')
```

To something like

```
if(context.fieldId === 'entity')
```

You're getting repeating output lines because whenever a field is changed, you're not doing a check on the current fieldId in the context object instead checking the `context.currentRecord.fieldId` which I'm not sure what evaluates to.

Check this out for more info: [fieldChanged(scriptContext)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4410692508.html)